# How can I handle async and await when using Xamarin MessagingCenter calling an async method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my VM I have this:

```
public ICommand FBtnCmd;

public PhrasesFrameViewModel(PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame) {
   FBtnCmd = new Command(() => MessagingCenter.Send<PhrasesFrameViewModel>(this, "FBtn"));
}
```

In the back-end C# I have this:

```
public PhrasesFrame()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PhrasesFrameViewModel>(this, "FBtn", (s) => this.FBtn());
}

async public  Task FBtn()
{
    // code here
    await Task.Run(() => App.DB.UpdateFavorite(phrase.Favorite, phrase.PhraseId));
    // code here
}
```

It's giving me a warning message saying that

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await'
>   operator to the result of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the warning is on the `Subscribe` line. This situation is similar to what happens with control event handlers which are also not asynchronous. The lambda `(s) => this.FBtn()` is basically a delegate `Action<PhrasesFrameViewModel>` and its signature has the return type of `void`. So if you start asynchronous work inside - like here with `FBtn`, you will "fire and forget", so the action will finish right after the first actual asynchronous work starts executing. This approach can be called "fire-and-forget" and it is not recommended, because if any exception occurs during the execution of `FBtn`, the exception will never propagate up and your application may get into an inconsistent state without you being able to know. If there is a possibility that `FBtn` could throw, you should use a `try...catch` block instead:

```
async (s) => try { await this.FBtn(); } catch { /* handle */ }
```

I had to make the lambda `async void` here, to be able to `await` the `FBtn` `Task`. Without `await`, the `FBtn` would fire and forget, and potential exception would not occur here, as it would be inside the `Task`, which is never `awaited` nor accessed via `GetResult()` or similar approach.

In short, you should always `await` your `Task` and avoid fire and forget. Only place where `async void` is okay is event handlers and situations like this, but you should always think about potential exceptions.

Comment: It does catch if `await` is used, event handlers are not special case compared to `Action` in this example or normal `async void` method, but `await` needs to be used for the `Task` exception to unwrap.

Comment: @Nkosi that article just reinforces Martin's argument. Read through the section again, and note that Martin has a `await` inside the try block. The example of the try/catch has no `await` in it.

Comment: It is a different case - in the linked article the exception handling is not in the `async void` method, but outside, which cannot be caught. But if the `try...catch` was moved inside, it would be caught.

Comment: I still however believe that the `Subscribe` action delegate above is not an event handler and would still fall into the async void fire and forget category

Comment: That is true, without the `await` it could be problem, but putting the `try...catch` inside the action at least gives a chance to catch the exceptions in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You would need an event handler to allow for async await to be used. That way `async void` can be avoided in the delegate, but allowed on event handlers.

```
public PhrasesFrame() {
    InitializeComponent();
    fRequested += onfRequested; //subscribe to event
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PhrasesFrameViewModel>(this, "FBtn", (s) => 
        //Raise event
        fRequested(s, EventArgs.Empty));
}

private event EventHandler fRequested = delegate { };
private async void onfRequested(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    //Await async task
    await FBtn();
}

public  async Task FBtn() {
    // code here
    await Task.Run(() => App.DB.UpdateFavorite(phrase.Favorite, phrase.PhraseId));
    // code here
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)